# How to handle third-party libraries that can potentially throw, without knowing what kind of exceptions they may have?

Tags: c#, exceptions

I'm starting to run into this sort of dilemma while many third-party APIs, but I will use MongoDB for my examples. Consider the following code:

```
var settings         = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(connectionString);
settings.ServerApi   = new ServerApi(ServerApiVersion.V1);
_mongoClient         = new MongoClient(settings);
_northAmericaServer  = _mongoClient.GetDatabase("server_na");
_userCollection      = _mongoDatabaseServers.GetCollection<Entry>("users");
_allUsers            = _userCollection.Find("{}");
```

There are, at least, 4 (meaningful) exceptions that may come out of that. Having an invalid connection string format, having bad credentials, `Entry` not being a proper representation of the database's documents, `Find()` using a malformed filter string, etc.

Since C# doesn't implement a `throws` clause, it isn't straightforwardly obvious to me exactly what can go wrong while using third-party APIs, such as this. The exceptions that I mentioned earlier came from my experience experimenting with MongoDB today.

Documentation (if any) doesn't necessarily point out that kind of thing, and even if it did you might not trust it unless it was somehow autogenerated to list every possible exception from a method call.

So ultimately, I have to peek at the source code of the library (in this case MongoDB's driver) to have a better idea of what kind of exceptions a particular method might throw.

There's been a question about finding out whether a method throws here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316535/how-to-know-if-some-method-can-throw-an-exception/18316567#18316567 (you can't, practically) - but that's not really the core of my problem: **I want to know how to properly approach a third-party API in a situation where I am unfamiliar with the things that can go wrong with it.**

I understand that exceptions aren't meant to be used for flow control, and that they often signal the application reaching an impossible state - and some exceptions are fatal and there's no point in trying to recover from them - but it seems reasonable for my application to try to address some of the exception(s) e.g. maybe my application can retrieve an up-to-date connection string from my authoritative server.

Again, it's not really about MongoDB in particular - it's just that I seem to have developed some degree of paranoia when calling any third-party API as I just don't know what can go wrong, and also a degree of disappointment when I think that I probably could've handled it reasonably if only I knew.

I could of course wrap the entire snippet in a `try catch` but that wouldn't afford me the precision I'm looking for.

What should a developer do when calling third-party APIs that could potentially throw, yet is unable to discern exactly how or when?

Comment: It's impossible to guarantee anything about other peoples' code so there aren't any  technical solutions, only mitigation, and indeed the nature of the problem at its core isn't really technical but human, so it needs human solutions and approaches. e.g. transparency with your stakeholders, a process which allows you to quickly respond to issues/incidents found in production, ongoing constructive engagement with users to understand their needs and manage their expectations,  a process which includes sufficient quality assurance, particularly including high automated test coverage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There simply is no good solution. You can read the documentation and hope that the documentation is complete, and eventually fix bugs as they are discovered.

It is also possible to write resilient programs that bound the effect of failures to a particular unit of work or component of the entire software system. For example in a web server, an exception while handling one request shouldn't take down the entire server, it should only make that one request fail.

Thus, it can be reasonable to have very broad try–catch wrappers in your code, without catching only library-specific exceptions. But this only makes sense if you can recover in some way. Whether this is possible depends on the structure of your application and on the requirements of your business logic.